# What is the “t” value in a Gaussian CDF, and how do I calculate it?

Tags: statistics, gaussian, cumulative-distribution-functions

I was reading up on the formula for a Gaussian CDF:

$\Phi(x) = \frac12 [1 + $erf$(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}})]$

where erf(x) is defined as:

erf$(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} $$\int_0^x e^{-t^2} \,dt$

My question is, what is the $t$ variable in the formula, and how do I calculate it?

Thanks to anyone that can offer some help.

Comment: $t$ is just the integration variable. It has no significance.

Comment: It is the dummy variable inside the integration

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Thanks for the responses!

Comment: $\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^x e^{-\Xi^2}\,d\Xi$$ would be the same thing.